# Fetch multiple records from php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am fetching records as follows:

```
$aResult = array();
$sql     = "SELECT notes FROM table WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$result  = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $aResult['query_result'] = $row;
}
```

This returns only the last record in the table. I need to return all records from the sql statement.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change you `$aResult['query_result'] = $row;` to `$aResult['query_result'][] = $row;`

You've override the result each time, so you just get one.

Comment: @KrisRoofe :) Simple and Perfect. +1 Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your loop constantly overwrites the value and hence you will only ever seen the last row. I think you might see better results if you do something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $aResult[] = $row;
}
```

so that each new row gets appended to your array

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code, currently You are initiating the values to the same array key :

```
$aResult = array();
$sql     = "SELECT notes FROM table WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
$result  = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $aResult['query_result'][] = $row;
}
```

for more Detail On [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)